# option select, check if the option selected or not?

Tags: php, html, html-select

I had search internet, most tutorial show how to if $what= what, echo 'selected', but I want to do something opposite, if this option selected, echo $what = what,look at my code below. I don't want to touch the javascript, is that possible to do it?

```html
<?php
<select id="post_show_per_page">
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="60" >60</option>
  <option value="90" >90</option>
  <option value="120" >120</option> 
   </select>
// check if #post_show_per_page value is 30, $post_show_per_page = 30;
// check if #post_show_per_page value is 60, $post_show_per_page = 60;

?>
```

Comment: First give your select element a name like `<select id="post_show_per_page" name="post_show_per_page">` then you can check if a value is submitted through the form like `if(isset($_REQUEST['post_show_per_page'])) { print $_REQUEST['post_show_per_page']; }`. Depending on how you send the form, through a post or get request, you can also check the value inside either `$_GET['post_show_per_page']` or `$_POST['post_show_per_page']`

Comment: How about at the first page load before user click send form, when user load the page first time, how do I check if selected or not?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? If you would like to check if the form has been sent, then your give the select element a name and then check if the value exists in `$_POST['post_show_per_page']`. If you would like to store this value then you need to use a database or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I guess I cannot do it at the beginning without form send. Can I store this value by using $_session or localstorage, you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you mean you want to do it on the client side (the user's computer, before they have clicked "submit"), look into the JavaScript `onchange` event. Nothing to do with PHP!

Comment: Or, if you mean you want to know which of the options is selected even before the user has made a choice, well, you can't. You will have to make the choice yourself by adding `selected` to the option you want to be selected by default.